# Angular Timer and Angular State Does Not Work Perfectly on Safari in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, timer, safari

I am currently using the [Angular Timer by Siddii](https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/). My current setup is like this:

```
<timer class="timer" ng-if="isPopup !== '1'" countdown="timer" max-time-unit="'minute'" interval="1000" finish-callback="expiry()"><span>{{mminutes}}</span> <span>{{sseconds}}</span></timer>
```

The `finish-callback` executes this:

```
    $scope.expiry = function() {
      JSON.stringify($payments.get('paymentoption').code);
      var result = {
        paymentoption: $payments.get('paymentoption'),
        expired: true
      };
      $interval.cancel(promise);
      $state.go('deposit.list', result);
    };
```

On all browsers (desktop and mobile), this works as expected. `$state.go` runs and redirects to the page I want to go to. This is a different case in Safari in iOS (iPhone 6). It just finishes the callback but stays on its current state.

Note that this bug happens depending on the length of time the value was set. I tested the timer from 1 minute up to 5 minutes and it works fine. When it goes around 10 minutes and up, it ends and stops there. Sometimes, it does not even finish the timer and just halts.

Is there something with iOS Safari that makes this behavior occur?